# Globalization and Localization: When? How?

Tags: asp.net, localization, internationalization, globalization

I'm researching a little about different ways to do Localization and Globalization in .NET as I was asked in my job to do it. However, I've been reading lot of posts about those topics, and I don't think that doing Globalization nor Localization is the best option for us:

Apparently bosses' plans are to duplicate the app in many servers as they need with different domains (.com, .es, .co, etc.) in order to use it in many different countries. As I see it, and please correct me if I'm wrong, doing that would imply that there's no need of Globalization nor Localization, because instead of having one application running and accepting different localized resources you will have many different apps running in different servers with different and exclusive resources...

Does it make any sense to implement globalization and localization if they're proceeding this way? Please help me clarify my thoughts.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: For what I see, if they're proceeding this way and replicating the app in different servers with different domains and resources, it would be better then to only modify the resources manually and setting culture info properly for each one, but that wouldn't be globalizing nor localizing anything =/ isn't it?

Comment: Are you going to fork the project and have it go separate ways? Or do you still want to maintain all versions together?

Comment: They would have it go in separate ways. Even different databases.

Comment: The only reason they want to do it this way is because at the moment of giving support or updating the app is better to publish the same thing three times than having to mantain it sepparetely. Isn't a better approach to this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would definitely implement localization and stick to 1 code base as much as possible.

You can deploy the same project to different servers and set a fixed culturecode if you have to or let it depend on the user's browser.

Just splitting your code because you want different languages without a localization mechanism is a bad idea. It will be horrible to maintain.

I have 1 project running for different clients on different domains with slightly different functionality and different languages and i am still sticking to 1 code base for all of them.